# Does Instrumentation API allow to completely redifine the class including its structure?

Tags: java, instrumentation

I'm reading the Instrumentation API docs and numerous examples found in web.
But still I can't understand what kind of things I can do to a class using Instrumentation API ?
Am I right in thinking that before the class is loaded I can do any transformation I want (add new fields, remove, add methods) but once it's loaded I am allowed only to change method bodies ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the JVM as to what changes are allowed.  Typically you need to keep the public API and all fields the same. You can change the code.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses%28java.lang.Class...%29

> The retransformation may change method bodies, the constant pool and attributes. The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance. These restrictions maybe be lifted in future versions. The class file bytes are not checked, verified and installed until after the transformations have been applied, if the resultant bytes are in error this method will throw an exception.

Comment: I think there is a difference between what actions are allowed and what are not depending on the stage. For example, Instrumentation API javadoc states:
`The retransformation may change method bodies, the constant pool and attributes. The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance. `
However I'm able to find many examples that add fields to classes at definition time (not redefinition).

Comment: For example, http://www.jsessionid.de/2011/03/inject-any-java-code-at-runtime.html

Comment: It appears you can perform almost any transformation before the class is loaded. e.g. I assume changing the classes name is not allowed. ;)

Comment: I am not sure but it seems in JDK 21 these limitation has been lifted. The part of the documentation in retransformClasses has this line in older JDKs "The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance" but this part has been removed in JDK 21 documentation.